# Unclear claim in Serre's Lie algebras and Lie groups 1964 Lectures

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, definition

The following is an excerpt from Serre's *Lie algebras and Lie groups 1964 Lectures* p.18:

> Let $X$ be a set and define inductively a family of sets $X_n$
>   $(n\ge1)$ as follows
>
> 1) $X_1=X$
>
> 2) $X_n=\bigsqcup_{p+q=n}X_p\times X_q$ $(n\ge 2)$ ($=$ disjoint
>   union).
>
> Put $M_X=\bigsqcup_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n$ and define $M_X\times
> M_X\rightarrow M_X$ by means of  $$X_p\times X_q\rightarrow
>  X_{p+q}\subset M_X,$$ where the arrow is the canonical inclusion
>   resulting from 2). The magma $M_X$ is called the free magma on $X$. An
>   element $w$ of $M_X$ is called a non-associative word on $X$. Its
>   length, $l(w)$, is the unique $n$ such that $w\in X_n$.
>
> ...
>
> Properties of the free magma $M_X$:
>
> 1. $M_X$ is generated by $X$.
> 2. $m\in M_X - X\iff$$m=u.v$, with $u,v\in M_X$; and $u,v$ are uniquely determined by $m$.

I don't understand why he says that $M_X$ is generated by $X$. Let 
$$\mathfrak{P}=\{Y\subset M_X\ |\ X\subset Y\ \land\ Y.Y\subset Y\}.$$
Then $\bigcap_{Y\in\mathfrak{P}} Y$ is the magma generated by $X$. It is clear that $M_X\in\mathfrak{P}$: thus, 
$$\bigcap_{Y\in\mathfrak{P}} Y\subset M_X.$$
But I don't see how $M_X\subset \bigcap_{Y\in\mathfrak{P}} Y$; specifically, if $w\in M_X$, how can we show that for all $Y\in\mathfrak{P}$, it is the case that $w\in Y$?

**Edit:**

Suppose $w\in M_X$. Let $Y\in\mathfrak{P}$. Then there exists $n\ge 1$ such that $w\in X_n$. If $n=1$, then $w\in X_1=X\subset Y$; i.e. $w\in Y$. If $n\ge 2$, then there exists $(w',w'')\in X_p\times X_q$ such that $p+q=n$ and $w=w'w''$. I am not exactly sure what the next step is, here, to prove that $w\in Y$. Must I induct on $n$?

Comment: The elements of $M_X$ are "non-associative words in X". Take as an example $u=x_1((x_2x_3)x_4)$. In your notation if $Y$ contains $X$ and is in $\mathfrak P$, then $x_2x_3\in Y$, then also $(x_2x_3)x_4\in Y$, then also $x_1((x_2x_3)x_4)\in Y$. Do you see how any non-associative word must lie in $Y$?

Comment: I think I get what you're saying; something like: if the magma $Y$ contains all the elements of $X$ then it must contain all the non-associative words of $X$. Is that correct? But I'm still not clear about how I can demonstrate this rigorously.

Comment: Any non-associative word is a product of two non-associative words of lesser length, so an induction on the length of the word will work.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.